# необходимо реализовать метод (Класс Unit1, метод revertString()), который переставит символы в строке

Tags: java, методы

Знаю что через `for`, а как именно не могу сообразить?

Можете подсказать? Код прилагаю. Это по `Java`.

Необходимо реализовать метод (Класс `Unit1`, метод `revertString()`), который переставит символы в строке (переменная `INPUT_STRING` внутри класса `Unit1`) в обратном порядке, без использования метода `reverse()` из класса `StringBuilder`.

В случае успеха в консоль будет выведено сообщение **"Строка изменена корректно"**

```
public class Unit1 {

private static final String INPUT_STRING = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, "
    + "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String result = revertString();
    checkResult(result);
}

/**
 * При реализации метода нельзя использовать метод reverse() из класса StringBuilder
 */
private static String revertString() {
    return "";
}

private static void checkResult(String result) {
    if (INPUT_STRING.equals(new StringBuilder(result).reverse().toString())) {
        System.out.println("Строка изменена корректно");
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("Ошибка, строка изменена неверно");
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Через стримы

```
//генерим индексы
return IntStream.range(0, INPUT_STRING.length())
   //выбираем нужный символ из строки
   .mapToObj((i) -> String.valueOf(INPUT_STRING.charAt(INPUT_STRING.length() - i - 1)))
   //соединяем воедино
   .collect(Collectors.joining());
```

То же самое через `for`

```
    //будующая строка
    String out = "";
    //перебираем индексы от последнего до 0
    for(int i = INPUT_STRING.length() - 1; i>=0; i--){
        //склеиваем
        out+=INPUT_STRING.charAt(i);
    }
    return out;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: А символы и строку любую получается берем?

Comment: да, любую. А что, вам надо как-то фильтровать? Я вам написал функции "перевертывания" строки. Сравнение ваше уже)

Answer (score 1):

Взять строку, разбить на массив символов, пройтись циклом от последнего индекса массива к нулевому, записывая их в новую строку, вернуть строку в метод. Все.